# Concerning an infinite server queue with Poisson arrivals

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, queueing-theory, poisson-process

Here's the statement of the problem (from Ross's *Introduction to Probability Models*):

[image]

For those unfamiliar with "infinite server queues," they are described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/%E2%88%9E_queue). In this case, however, the service times are not exponentially distributed; rather, they are distributed according to some common distribution $G$. It follows that $X(t)$, the number of customers that have completed service by time $t$ and that arrived at time $s, s\le t,$ is Poisson distributed with mean

$$E[X(t)]=\lambda \int_{0}^{t}G(t-s)ds=\lambda \int_{0}^{t}G(y)dy.$$

Similarly, the distribution of $Y(t)$, the number of customers being served at time $t$ and that arrived at time $s, s \le t,$ is Poisson distributed with mean

$$E[Y(t)]=\lambda \int_{0}^{t}\bar G(t-s)ds=\lambda \int_{0}^{t}\bar G(y)dy$$

where $\bar G(t-s) = 1 - G(t-s)$.

Now, for part $(a)$, let $A =\{\text{the first customer to arrive is also the first to depart} \}$, i.e., our desired event; and suppose the first customer arrives at time $0$ and departs at time $t$. Then, we consider the event $A$ conditioned on the event in which $0$ customers have completed service by time $t$, i.e.,

$$ \mathbb P[A | X(t) = 0] = \exp\left\{ -\lambda \int_{0}^{t}G(y)dy\right\}.  $$

Ok, I get that. But then, for some reason, the following is the answer:

$$ \mathbb P[A] = \int_{0}^{\infty} \left( \exp\left\{ -\lambda \int_{0}^{t}G(y)dy\right\} \right) dG(t).  $$

And I don't really understand where this comes from. If anybody could shed some light on this, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: You should condition on the service time of the first customer.

Comment: Q: As I'm solving these same problems (and I don't know how to tackle cases c) and d) with general service time), are there answers available? Can you solve the last two cases?

Comment: With service time exponential, cases c) and d) are not hard to solve by utilizing the memorylessness property.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given an empty system at time $0$ the number of departures by time $t$ is a non homogeneous Poisson process with rate
$$\lambda(t)=\lambda\int^{t}_{0}G(y)dy$$
and so the probability of no departures by time $t$ is given by:
$$exp(-\lambda\int^{t}_{0}G(y)dy)$$
now if we set time $0$ to be time of the first arrival and let $G_1$ be the service time of the first arrival then we have:
$$P(A|G_1=t)=exp(-\lambda\int^{t}_{0}G(y)dy)$$
now we have
$$P(A)=\int^{\infty}_{0}P(A|G_1=t)dG_1(t)=$$
$$\int^{\infty}_{0}P(A|G_1=t)dG(t)=$$
$$\int^{\infty}_{0}exp\left(-\lambda\int^{t}_{0}G(y)dy\right)dG(t)$$